# Split array to multidimensional array by the beginning character in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

For example, I want the array

```
["ABC", "ADE", "BCD", "HYD", "ZYX", "ZZZ"]
```

to be converted into:

```
[
    ["ABC", "ADE"],
    ["BCD"],
    ["HYD"],
    ["ZYX", "ZZZ"],
]
```

So how can I achieved this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use your array to create an intermediate dictionary that maps the initial letter to an array of strings that start with that letter, then create the final array from the dictionary:

**Using `Dictionary(grouping:by)`**

The dictionary can now be created using [`Dictionary(grouping:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init):

```
let arr = ["ABC", "ADE", "BCD", "HYD", "ZYX", "ZZZ"]

let dict = Dictionary(grouping: arr, by: { $0.prefix(1) })
print(dict)
```

> ```
> ["H": ["HYD"], "A": ["ABC", "ADE"], "B": ["BCD"], "Z": ["ZYX", "ZZZ"]]
> ```

```
let arr2 = dict.keys.sorted().compactMap { dict[$0] }
print(arr2)
```

> ```
> [["ABC", "ADE"], ["BCD"], ["HYD"], ["ZYX", "ZZZ"]]
> ```

**Note:** I used `.prefix(1)` instead of `.first!` because `prefix(1)` will not crash if the original array contains an empty string `""`.

---

**Original answer:**

```
let arr = ["ABC", "ADE", "BCD", "HYD", "ZYX", "ZZZ"]

var dict = [Character : [String]]()

for str in arr {
    if let first = str.first {
        dict[first, default: []] += [str]
    }
}

print(dict)
```

> ```
> ["A": ["ABC", "ADE"], "H": ["HYD"], "B": ["BCD"], "Z": ["ZYX", "ZZZ"]]
> ```

```
let arr2 = dict.keys.sorted().map { dict[$0]! }
print(arr2)
```

> ```
> [["ABC", "ADE"], ["BCD"], ["HYD"], ["ZYX", "ZZZ"]]
> ```

Comment: nice one. You can also use `guard let first = str.characters.first else { continue }`

Comment: this is perfect for using in a contact list tableview data source with sections